# How to compute the sum $\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi}{9}\right)+\cot^2\left(\frac{2\pi}{9}\right)+\cot^2\left(\frac{4\pi}{9}\right)=~?$

Tags: trigonometry

How to compute the sum of $\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi}{9}\right)+\cot^2\left(\frac{2\pi}{9}\right)+\cot^2\left(\frac{4\pi}{9}\right)=~?$

The answer is $9$.

I tried to use the formula $\cot (2\theta)=\dfrac{\cot^2\theta-1}{2\cot\theta}$ but it is getting more and more complicated.

Comment: Hint: Observe that your required summation can be computed from computing the summation $\sum_{i=1}^8 \cot ^2 \frac{i\pi}{9}$. And if $z$ is $e^{iA}$, then $\cot A = \bar{z}^2 - z^2$, try to link  $\sum_{i=1}^8 \cot ^2 \frac{i\pi}{9}$ with the 9th roots of unity.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Ccot%5E2%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B9%7D%2B%5Ccot%5E2%5Cfrac%7B2%5Cpi%7D%7B9%7D%2B%5Ccot%5E2%5Cfrac%7B4%5Cpi%7D%7B9%7D%24&p=3), there's the AoPS thread [simplification of trigonometric expression](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2133845p15618154).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S= \cot^2\frac{\pi}{9}+\cot^2\frac{2\pi}{9}+\cot^2\frac{4\pi}{9}$ and note that $\cot \frac{4\pi}9=\tan\frac{\pi}{18}$

$$\begin{align}
S&=\frac{1}{\sin^2\frac{\pi}9} -1+\frac{1}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}9}-1+\frac{1}{\cos^2\frac{\pi}{18}}-1 \\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}9}+\frac{1+4\sin^2\frac{\pi}{18}}{\sin^2\frac{\pi}{9}}-3\\
\\
&=\frac{1+4\cos^2\frac{\pi}{9}\left(1+4\sin^2\frac{\pi}{18}\right)}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}{9}}-3\\
\\
&=\frac{7+6\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}-4\cos\frac{\pi}{9}-4\cos\frac{\pi}{9}\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}{9}}-3\\
\\
&=\frac{6-6\cos\frac{\pi}{9}+6\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}{9}}-3\\
\\
&=\frac{6\cos\frac{\pi}{9}\left(2\cos\frac{\pi}{9}-1\right)}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}{9}}-3\\
\\
&=\frac{24\cos\frac{\pi}{9}\left(\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}\sin\frac{\pi}{9}\right)}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}{9}}-3\\
\\
&=12-3\\
\\
&=9 \end{align}$$

Comment: How did you conclude that the final fraction is equal to $12$?

Comment: $2\cos\frac{\pi}{9}\sin\frac{\pi}{9}=\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}$ @Zima

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that, nice one.

Comment: Wow nice Method.

Comment: Take factor $2$ out and write $\frac12=\cos\frac{\pi}3$ @spock

Answer (score 0):

L.H.S. $=\cot^2(20°) +\cot^2(40°) +\cot^2(80°).$

Let $A = 20°$ then $3A = 60°$ hence
$\cot(3A)=\cot(60°)= \frac1{\sqrt3}.$

L.H.S $=\cot^2 A +\cot^2 (60°-A) +\cot^2 (60° + A).$

Write in terms of tan and use tan(A-B)  formula to simplify.

$=\frac1{\tan^2 A} + \frac1{\tan^2 (60°-A)} +\frac1{\tan^2 (60° + A)}.$

$= {(6tan^6 A} + {45 tan^4A} +9)/(3 tanA - tan^3A)^2.$

Replace $\tan^6A$ with the help of $\tan^2(3A)=3$

$ tan^6 A =  33 tan^4A - 27tan^2A +3.$

Final step is $27\cot^2(3A)=\frac{27}3 = 9.$

Comment: How do you "simplify the above statement" and get that "final step"?

Comment: By using tan(A-B) and tan 3A formulas. I am new to syntax. Thanks a ton for helping me.